# Setting a Max Boundary is not working Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I seem to be unable to set a Max Boundary, so that the map bounces back after the user has reached a certain point. Also every time I've tired to change the fitbounds() code the map disappears from my Website.

I've looked at the Leaflet documentation over and over again, with very little luck and been looking through Google for any answers and all the code I have tried has not work. I believe I'm missing or not seeing something really simple.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to restrict the view to a given geographical boundary, the simplest solution is to set the [`maxBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-maxbounds) option. Unless you want to do it dynamically, in which case the option to use is [`setMaxBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-setmaxbounds). The [`fitBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-fitbounds) method seems redundant and may actually be the reason why you aren't getting the desired outcome.

```
var southWest = L.latLng(52.456009,-10.685582);
var northEast = L.latLng(51.699800,5.215615); 

var maxBoundArea = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.map('map', {        
    zoomControl:true, 
    maxNativeZoom:28, 
    minZoom:8, 
    maxBounds: maxBoundArea
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :-) Welcome to StackOverflow btw!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing a constrain function

```
function constrain(n,low,high){
    return Math.max(Math.min(n, high), low);
}
```

* Note: I did not think of this myself, it is a function in p5 and thought it might work*

Documentation:

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/0.7.3/src/math/calculation.js#L76